# Associate RData file with RStudio so that it can be opened from OS

Tags: rstudio

I am working in RStudio under Windows 11. Very often I save my data/environment using `save()` command and then load that .RDat file with `load()` command. I am searching for a way to optimize it slightly, i.e. to "open" the rdat file directly from the OS, so that double-click or Enter key from Windows Explorer or other file manager should load the file in the active RStudio session. I tried associating the .RDat extension with RStudio, but then it attempts to open it as a source file which doesn't work of course. Any other ideas? In worst case I am ok even to use external tools like AutoHotKey etc. but can't find a working solution so far.